# Trying to make a word scrambler but cannot resolve random.nextint()

Tags: java

```
public class Random {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();
        String word = "Animals";

        System.out.println("Before: " + word );
        word = scramble( r, word );
        System.out.println("After : " + word );
    }

    public static String scramble(Random random, String inputString) {
        char a[] = inputString.toCharArray();
      
        for( int i=0 ; i<a.length ; i++ ) {
            int j = random.nextInt(a.length); // nextInt() is undefined for type Random
           
            char temp = a[i]; a[i] = a[j];  a[j] = temp;
        }       

        return new String(a);
    }
}
```

I'm attempting to make a program that takes a user imputed word and scrambles it and returns it. However, I cannot get around this one error.

Comment: You named your class `Random`, the `r` you instanciate it THAT type, your own, not the java.util.Random one

Comment: This works for me. Do you use java.util.Random?

Comment: **NEVER** name a class, a variable like an existing (and used) class, package, ...

Comment: That worked. I had the name of the class as Random and that confused everything. I just had to add java.util.Random

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.util.Random` instead of your defined class `Random`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't name your class `Random`, it doesn't allow you to import and use the real `java.util.Random;`. Remember to **never** name a class like an existing one, use something relative to YOUR usecase

```java
import java.util.Random;

class ScrambleTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();
        String word = "Animals";
        System.out.println("Before: " + word);
        word = scramble(r, word);
        System.out.println("After : " + word);
    }

    public static String scramble(Random random, String inputString) {
        char[] a = inputString.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            int j = random.nextInt(a.length);
            char temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;
        }
        return new String(a);
    }
}
```